# Javascript- How to access specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var id = '';
var result=[];
var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?type=movie&apikey="+api_key;


function handle(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    $("#form1").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    })
    var search_value = $("#search").val();
    if(search_value==""){
      alert("Please enter a movie name!")
    }
    else{
    $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url+"&t="+search_value,
    success: function(data){
    id = data.Title
    result.push(`<div class="container resultcont">
              <img src="${data.Poster}" class="img-thumbnail poster float-left" width="150px" height="150px"/>
              <p>Title: ${data.Title}</p>
              <p> Genre: ${data.Genre}</p>
              <p> Release Date: ${data.Released}</p>
              <p> Runtime: ${data.Runtime}</p>
              <p>Ratings: ${data.imdbRating}</p>
              <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" id="wlbtn ${id}" onclick="watchlist()">Add</button>
              </div>
              <br>`)
            
    parameter = parameter + `<div class="container resultcont">
                  <img src="${data.Poster}" class="img-thumbnail poster float-left" width="150px" height="150px"/>
                  <p>Title: ${data.Title}</p>
                  <p> Genre: ${data.Genre}</p>
                  <p> Release Date: ${data.Released}</p>
                  <p> Runtime: ${data.Runtime}</p>
                  <p>Ratings: ${data.imdbRating}</p>
                  </div>
                  <br>`

    $("#searchresultdiv").html(result)
    }
    })
    }
   
  }
}

function watchlist(){
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style","display:none")
  var remove_btn = `<button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" float="right" id="wlbtn" onclick="removewatchlist()">Remove</button>`
  $("#watchlistdiv").html(parameter+remove_btn)
}
```

I am pushing the search results into the result array. So each result is in a div resultcont.

So the problem i have is, I want to do some manipulation specific to the resultcont's button. For example: [image]

So if i click on hulk's add button, only that div should get added to watchlist. How to only add hulk's div without adding avenger's div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would not recommend that you have space in your ID so `wlbtn ${id}` becomes `wlbtn_${id}`

Second inside your watchlist function you use `ID` but the function don't know the reference to `ID` same goes for `parameter`

```
function watchlist(obj) {
  $(obj).prop("disabled", true);
  var remove_btn = `<button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" float="right" id="wlbtn" onclick="removewatchlist()">Remove</button>`
  $(obj).after(remove_btn)
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function watchlist(obj) {
  $(obj).hide()
  var remove_btn = `<button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" float="right" id="` + $(obj).attr("id") + `_remove" onclick="removewatchlist(this)">Remove</button>`
  $(obj).after(remove_btn)
  $(obj).closest(".card").appendTo(".watchlist");
}

function removewatchlist(obj){
 $(obj).closest(".card").remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div>HULK</div>
  <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" id="wlbtn_1" onclick="watchlist(this)">Add hulk</button><br>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div>AVENGERS</div>
  <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" id="wlbtn_2" onclick="watchlist(this)">Add Avengers</button><br>
</div>
<div class="watchlist">
  <h2>Watchlist</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the question, Could you please provide the code to the updated question if you dont mind,

Comment: @xBatmanx Demo updated, it should be enough to give you an idea about how to move on from here.

Comment: @xBatmanx you are very welcome